# "audio"タグを"select"タグとリンクさせる方法

Tags: javascript, html

下記のソースコードは、"bgsound"タグを"select"タグとリンクさせて選曲できるように
設定したものです。
しかし、この"bgsound"タグは廃止されるとのことですので、これを"audio"タグに変えたい
のですが、どのように書き換えればいいのでしょうか。ご教示ください。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
   function selectBgm(e){
    var selectedIndex = e.selectedIndex;
        bgm.src= e[selectedIndex].value; 
}
 //-->
</script>

         <bgsound id="bgm" src="" loop="-1">

 <form id="bgms" style="text-align:right">
    <SELECT id="bgmSelector" onchange="selectBgm(this);">
      <OPTION  value=""  selected>選曲(停止)</OPTION>
      <OPTION  value="１１１.mp3">１１１</OPTION>
      <OPTION  value="２２２.wav">２２２</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

この場合は、[`<audio>`タグ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Events)とその[`autoplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)という属性を使用すると、どうでしょうか。特に、下記のコード例の`<audio id="bgm" autoplay></audio>`のところですが。

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectBgm(e) {
  var selectedIndex = e.selectedIndex;
  bgm.src= e[selectedIndex].value; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="bgm" autoplay></audio>
<form id="bgms" style="text-align:right">
  <SELECT id="bgmSelector" onchange="selectBgm(this);">
    <OPTION  value=""  selected>選曲(停止)</OPTION>
    <OPTION  value="１１１.mp3">１１１</OPTION>
    <OPTION  value="２２２.wav">２２２</OPTION>
  </SELECT>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

このコードと同じことを試しましたが、ファイル形式が"mp3"のときは鳴るのですが、"Wave"形式や"MIDI"形式のときは鳴りません。対応していないファイル形式があるのですね。

Comment: あっ、そうですか。じゃ、その場合には、`<audio>`タグに
[`type="audio/wav"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Examples)という属性を使うのは
いかがでしょうか？ブラウザによる振る舞いが異なるかもしれませんが、例えば、私の場合は、Chromeでは`wav`というファイルを`type`の属性なしで、使用することが出来ましたが。

Comment: type="audio/wave"は試しましたが、IEでは鳴りませんでした。
"audio"タグも、いろいろ制約があるみたいですね。

Comment: あっ、IEのことで、ごめんなさいー。`audio`タグは制約があるかもしれませんが、IE自体も制約がたくさんあると思いますね。ですから、Microsoft自体はIEの代わりに[より新しいブラウザ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge)を作成しています。